# Please prevent the redirect when migrating questions

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, migration

When migrating a question; if I cast the final vote which migrates the question I get redirected to the destination site.

This is mildly irritating - can this be changed so that I stay on the source site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great idea - this will be in tonight's push.

Answer (score 5):

I agree.  When closing it'd be better to stay on the question, or even be redirected back to the home page of the site, instead of going to the target site.  Just send future viewers of the closed question to the migrated question.